# Hide the title of a form element?

Tags: forms, 6

I'd like to use placeholders instead of labels for a form built with the form API.

I can get placeholders working well with the [Elements](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) module, but now I want to hide the labels. If I just set `['#title'] = NULL;` then form errors don't have descriptive names, and it ruins accessibility.

In Drupal 7, you could set the `#title_display` to `invisible` ([documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title_display)). Was something like this backported in a contrib module somewhere?

Or is there a way I can set my own class on the `label` element?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 is a lot more limited than 7 or 8 in this regard, and I'm not aware of any effort to backport this functionality.

However, Drupal 7 and 8 use the .visually-hidden CSS class to hide the label, and it's not very hard to make Drupal 6 do the same.

It's possible to add classes to a form element label with a theme function, but I've found this hard work. A much easier approach is the use the #prefix and #suffix attributes to wrap the element in a div tag. For example:

```
$form['test'] => array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Test'
  '#prefix' => '<div class="hide-label">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
);
```

Then you just need to add the following CSS:

```
.hide-label label {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

The contents of this class are copied from Drupal 8's .visually-hidden.

Hope this solves your problem.

James

Answer (score 0):

You could override the [theme_form_element()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6) function in your theme's template.php so that the label does not output:

```
// Remove  from output
```

function THEMENAME_form_element($element, $value) {
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

$output = '\n";
  $required = !empty($element['#required']) ? '*' : '';

if (!empty($element['#title'])) {
    $title = $element['#title'];
    if (!empty($element['#id'])) {
      $output .= $t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required));
    }
    else {
      $output .= '$t('!title: !required', array('!title' => filter_xss_admin($title), '!required' => $required));
    }
  }

$output .= " $value\n";

if (!empty($element['#description'])) {
    $output .= ' ' . $element['#description'] . "\n";
  }

$output .= "\n";

return $output;
}

Alternatively, you could target the form id > label and set it to display:none without modifying the theme function.